# BYTE3, does it mean the third or fourth byte of an int? IDB file that's already supplied

Tags: disassembly, ida, c, c++

I've got a program that i'm trying to debug a little bit by trying to make sense of a function or two, there's already some info that i've downloaded via a idb file and it's helped me get somewhere. But i'm kind of stuck on a part where i've got something like this:

```
BYTE3(v1) = 0;
```

This is from the ida hex-rays plugin which has made some nice c-pseudo code for me. I can't double click the function and get it translated in some way so i don't really know how to understand what it does, my guess is that it takes either the third or fourth byte of an int. So my question is, how would i be able to find this function and look at it's disassembly at least if it can't be translated by hex-rays? The signature if that helps at all looks like this according to ida: `_BYTE __fastcall(int)`

Comment: Yes, it sets the fourth byte of `v1`. Place your cursor inside the expression `BYTE3(v1)`, hit `Tab`, it'll switch to the corresponding place in the disassembly view.

Comment: Oh, didn't know about that, thanks alot!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All Hex-Rays macros are defined in **<IDA directory>\plugins\defs.h**. It's also available at https://github.com/nihilus/hexrays_tools/blob/master/code/defs.h

For `BYTE3(x)`:

```
...
#define BYTEn(x, n)   (*((_BYTE*)&(x)+n))
...
#define BYTE3(x)   BYTEn(x,  3)
...
```

So `BYTE3(x)` yields `(*((_BYTE*)&(x)+3))`, which effectively means the fourth byte of the value `x`.