# Hex Rays - strange functions __ROL4__ and __ROR4__

Tags: ida, decompilation, c

What's purpose of functions **ROL** and **ROR**?
For both of them, first arg is **int**, and second is **byte**

I suppose that's bitwise shifts

[image: two muppet[![rol and ror]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CYls.png)s][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEIBb.jpg)

Comment: [A simple search for ROR and ROL](https://www.google.com/search?q=ror+rol&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b) gives the answer right away https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift

Comment: [x86 Instruction Set Reference - RCL/RCR/ROL/ROR](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_273.html)

Comment: I'd already known that it's some kind of shifts and just needed qualification - at least there're two versions - for 16-bit values (__ROR2__) and for 32-bit (__ROR4__). Thanx for @mikfig

Comment: See [BYTE3, does it mean the third or fourth byte of an int? IDB file that's already supplied](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/byte3-does-it-mean-the-third-or-fourth-byte-of-an-int-idb-file-thats-already)

Comment: [don't put code in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714). Copy and paste here would be much faster and more convenient for others to use

Comment: Just in case someone find similar code:
The series of Rol4 Ror4 are indeed bit rotation, and from the constant we can see it is some MD5 computation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out IDA directory\plugins\defs.h.

```
...
// Macros to represent some assembly instructions
// Feel free to modify them

#define __ROL__(x, y) __rotl__(x, y)       // Rotate left
#define __ROR__(x, y) __rotr__(x, y)       // Rotate right
...
```

The [`__rotl__`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=111,4411,4411&text=_rotl) and [`__rotr__`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=111,4411,4411,4412&text=_rotr) are just for the `rol` and `ror` instructions